# Mathematical letter symbols

Tags: symbols

How I will be able to get the symbols [image] 
in LaTeX?

Comment: `$\mathcal{M}$` and `$\mathcal{Q}$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{MQ}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]